# Show only tagged with particular name items in Logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I'm creating log items with code line:

```
Log.d("myTag", "my message");
```

How to show only messages with tag `myTag` in `Logcat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `grep` output of logcat, but probably better choice is to use [Pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat):

```
pidcat com.you.package -t myTag
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution, but it may be helpful:

Search `myTag`, in the search bar found in the logCat; This way all the log will be filtered by the typed phrase.